# How to create a file in Scid-vs-pc; new chess pieces?

Tags: software, scid

I am a Linux hobbyist and I would like to know if someone could help me understand what steps I should follow to create this chess piece file in scid-vs-pc:

http://gorgonian.weebly.com/scid-vs-pc.html

> NOTE: piece data is contained in a text file which should be saved in
> the \ bin \ pieces sub-folder of the main SCID vs. PC directory (it
> needs to be created).

When I open the page there is nothing that can direct me to 'save' anything, it is just a text that the most I could do is to copy and paste ... in a file that I can previously create in my 'home' ... but, in bin? -- they give a different path: bin / pieces, I don't understand, I'm a dilettante.
Could someone please briefly indicate the steps ...? Thanks.

Comment: I guess those instructions about the bin folder are for Windows. Take a look here: http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/doc/Board.htm

Answer (score 1):

The info is here: http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/doc/Board.htm

- Create a pieces folder in ~/.scidvspc (~ means your home folder in linux).
- Create a file fritz.txt with the content of http://gorgonian.weebly.com/uploads/1/7/2/2/17221082/fritz.txt
- Save fritz.txt in  ~/.scidvspc/pieces
- Restart your scid-vs-pc
- Enjoy